# How to execute package for one submodule only on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, sbt

I have a sbt project with 4 modules: `module-a`, `module-b`, `module-c`, `module-d`.

Each module can be packaged as a WAR. I want to set up a deployment on Jenkins that would build only one of the 4 modules and deploy it to a container.

In detail, I want to have 4 Jenkins jobs - `job-a`, `job-b`, `job-c`, `job-d`, each building only the defined module (a to d).

For now, I am using `clean update test package` as the command for the Jenkins sbt build, but this results in packaging all 4 modules that is not necessary.

I already tried `project -module-a clean update test package` but with no luck.

Comment: Can you describe what in particular didn't work when changing to the project?

Comment: It works, but it still packages all modules instead of only one.
"./sbt project -module-a clean update test package" - This is the command i tried in jenkins

Comment: Quote the argument to `project` and don't use a dash: `./sbt "project module-a" clean update test`.

Comment: Thanks! It works! - Can you add an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quote the argument to project, i.e. `project module-a`, and don't use a dash before the name of the submodule.

The entire command line for the Jenkins job would than be as follows:

```
./sbt "project module-a" clean update test
```

Comment: I wish there was consistency between shell and batch mode here.

Answer (score 16):

You may also like to execute project-scoped `clean` and `test` tasks as follows:

```
sbt module-a/clean module-a/test
```

The solution is slightly shorter and clearer as to what project the following commands apply to.

You don't need to execute `update` task since it's implicitly executed by `test` as described in `inspect tree test`.

There's a way to make it cleaner with an alias. Use the following in the `build.sbt`:

```
addCommandAlias("jenkinsJob4ModuleA", "; module-a/clean; module-a/test")
```

With the alias, execute `jenkinsJob4ModuleA` to have the same effect as the above solution.