# How to execute tests in a single project only in multi-module build?

Tags: sbt

I have a multi-module build, and would like to run tests for different sub-projects  independently.

Is there a way to do this in sbt, e.g. if my multi-project build has a `core` and `commons` projects, I'd like to only run `test` in the `commons` project.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Run `sbt commons/test`. See detailed explanation in [Scopes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Scopes.html).

You may also use the combination of two commands from sbt - changing the current project using `project` and executing `test` afterwards.

```
sbt "project commons" test
```

You can also use

```
sbt "; project commons; test"
```

Answer (score 17):

It you are running `sbt` in interactive mode:

```
> project commons
> test
```

You can switch back to `core` with:

```
> project core
```

Answer (score 6):

Never mind, I came across this: 
[How to execute package for one submodule only on Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075820/sbt-package-only-one-submodule-on-jenkins)

```
sbt "project core" test
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this.

Get into SBT interactive mode

> sbt

sbt:core> commons / test

No need to switch between projects.

Answer (score 1):

to run sbt test only for ONLY the submodules having added, modified on deleted files, if you use git:

```
 while read -r proj ; do sbt "project $proj" test ; \
 done < <(git status --porcelain | cut -c 3- | cut -d/ -f1
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to have sbt open for a particular module.
Go to the location of the module directory and type in the "sbt" command.

sbt will then open in interactive mode for that module only