# Flyway migration (multi project): run SBT command for main module, but not submodule

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt

I have a play framework project which has a client library as a submodule. I'm using flyway for database migrations. When I use a command for flyway (such as `sbt flywayMigrate`), it runs that command twice, once against the root project, and once against the client library submodule.

Is there a way to run an SBT command against only the project, and not any of the submodules?
`sbt clientLibrary/flywayMigrate` will run the command against only the submodule, but `sbt root/flywayMigrate` runs the command against both.

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075820/how-to-execute-package-for-one-submodule-only-on-jenkins) which addresses running only one submodule, but does not help with running only the main module and no submodule.

EDIT:
I do have the client library in the aggregate for the root, and removing it runs commands just for the root by default. However I think having all the modules run by default is desirable, and I'd like to specify module exclusion rather than inclusion.

Comment: Maybe that will help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39551712/sbt-unidoc-how-to-exclude-a-sub-module-from-a-rootproject

Comment: @AlexeySoshin it does point me in a direction, I'll update my question with more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Multi-Project.html#Aggregation:

> In the project doing the aggregating, the root project in this case, you can control aggregation per-task. For example, to avoid aggregating the update task:
>
> ```
> lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
>   aggregate(util, core).
>   settings(
>     aggregate in update := false
>   )
> ```

In your case, set `aggregate in flywayMigrate := false` instead. To do this just once,

```
sbt "; set aggregate in (ThisBuild, flywayMigrate) := false; root/flywayMigrate"
```

should work.